# Why my dataset is not committed to my Oracle database using DBUnit and @DatabaseSetup annotation

Tags: spring, spring-transactions, dbunit

I'm new to spring and DbUnit.
I configured my DBUnitDatabaseConnection correct.
I'm using the @DatabaseSetup(..) to insert a dataset.
when requesting these data over my auto wired DAO-object, i am finding all my data.
All is fine, but when i want to access the data over a REST request, i can't find any data, because they are not committed and saved to my oracle database.
My data are committed after my test finished.
How can i achieve that my data getting committed before my test method starts?
Clearing and flushing my session doesn't work either.

UPDATE:
These annotations are used in my testclass:

- @DiertiesContext
- @Transactional
- @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
- @DbUnitConfiguration(databaseConnection = "dbConnection")
- @ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes=MyBeanConfig.class)
- @TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class, TransactionDbUnitTestExecutionListener.class})

my dbConnection Bean has set "defaultAutoCommit" to "true", and "dataTypeFactory" to "Oracle10DataTypeFactory". My java-based configuration also enables TransactionManagement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of clearing and flushing the session, i committed the current transaction.
That's working.